# Best Way to store hash In MYSQL DB and Indexing it (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, hash, pack, unpack

I recently learned to use UUID, and I use UUIDShortener(https://packagist.org/packages/keiko/uuid-shortener) to get a string I can use to share publicly in URL (ex: mavTAjNm4NVztDwh4gdSrQ)

I want this to be indexed pretty well in mySQL DB so SQL can retrive this data very fast among millions of rows.

What is the best way to store this string in InnoDB indexing motor (pretty sure Varchar would be the worst to use)

I envisage to use pack and unpack function in PHP to get a binary or an Integer that mySql would indexed fast, but never used thoses functions...

What would be the best options for packing data using pack here?
And what would be the Type of the column in Mysql?

If anyone could help,

Thanks

Comment: *"pretty sure Varchar would be the worst to use"* — Why?

Comment: Why do you need to combine a UUID and a hash? Wouldn't it be enough to use just one of both?

Comment: Also, if you want to use a **hash**, how does this related to packing and unpacking? A hash usually cannot be reversed

Comment: Because indexing and selecting varchar among large number of rows is slow compared to Integer and binary, isn't it?

Comment: I said hash, but in fact it is a string (shortened UUID)

Comment: Having a hash (a string stored as varchar) with a proper index the the column should be fast enough in the majority of cases. Are you having any performance issues, or is it a case of premature optimization?

Comment: There’s a good article about this [here](https://stitcher.io/blog/optimised-uuids-in-mysql). Binary is generally fastest, but it is very annoying when debugging and logging, FYI. You could also look at [ULID](https://github.com/ulid/spec) instead for a more human-sortable representation

Comment: And in the coming MariaDB, UUID will be a [native type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/).

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, especially if you didn't want to use the term "hash" in the first place

Comment: @NicoHaase hashes can be a legit method to reduce long string lookups.  Ie:  md5 a user agent string and use the resulting hash as the index.  If the work is distributed on the hashing it can save a lotta work / storage on the DB end.  When you’re dealing with a few billion clicks a day shortening long string lookups is… helpful.

Comment: @MasonStedman A UUID has 32 characters, I would not name that a "long string". Also, a hash cannot get unpacked as requested by the OP, so I don't think that the approach looks good. But feel free to add an answer if you think otherwise